# Why are graphic displays still so expensive?

Tags: lcd, display, tft, oled

As a new electronics enthusiast, I've been able to score a lot of components for very cheap, ranging from beefy MCUs in the 10$ ballpark to heaps of ICs for sub-dollar prices. However, buying a [coffee-maker-sized OLED screen](https://nl.farnell.com/midas/mcob128064t1v-wp/display-oled-cob-128x64-pixels/dp/2769702) cost me roughly 50$. Meanwhile, I can buy a [computer monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CVL2D2S) for 90$, although they're full HD, 60Hz full color screens.

Why are the components relatively so expensive?

Comment: I can tell you that even in 100k+ per year volumes, this very question still stands and something I wondered over too when I tried to upgrade a high volume consumer product into the 21:st century.

Comment: @winny OLED is the most advanced type of display though, and the lines that manufacture them are the most highly specialized and new ones. I suspect it's kinda like how 16nm costs waaaay more to manufacture than .18um, and unless you have the huge volume and specific need for it, .18um will be much cheaper to use?

Comment: @JorenVaes I checked all types, even regular LCD. Seems price is ax + b where x is number of pixels, a is really low and b is prohibitively high.

Answer (score 2):

It's also to do with supply chain.

A component you buy on digikey or RS etc has a very significant price overhead attached to it. You are paying for the convenience of the supplier (digikey or RS) cataloguing items, packing, shipping,

A finished LCD monitor as product can benefit from all the advantages of volume production and the efficiency that comes with it.

When it comes to displays versus integrated circuits, there is another difference: Displays are usually made custom to-order. It was somewhat different when it came to 2-row alphanumeric displays, but things like OLED displays are not standardized. When I design a product with a display that will be manufactured in the hundreds of thousands (or even less), I will talk to a display manufacturer directly, and have them built to-order my design. The displays sold by distributors are so expensive because another intermediate company actually designs, orders, and assembles the display as a module, and then sells it to the distributors you buy from. They are targeted at prototyping/low volume, where that cost is insignificant in the scheme of a product-development cycle. This can also be seen in the price.

It is somewhat similar to integrated DC/DC bricks. You can make DC/DC assemblies with the same performance for a fraction of the BOM and assembly cost, but the design cost, and the benefits of having that product *now*, outweigh the higher cost of a pre-made module.

Answer (score 0):

It's partly the difference between OLED and LCD and partly where you're shopping.

Comment: But it seems to be the same for LCD displays though? https://www.digikey.nl/products/nl/optoelectronics/display-modules-lcd-oled-graphic/107?k=Lcd

Comment: you won't get prices that are competitive with consumer products from parts distributors  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2043862354.html - these STN LCD display have failry poor contrast, but are cheap

Answer (score 0):

Note the price curve. One is expensive.

But even the 10-off price is considerably cheaper, then it flattens out for a little more saving at 25, 100.

Consider it may be worth buying 10 and keeping the spares for future projects. You're investing a lot by writing software to drive it anyway; you may as well make that effort pay down the cost of future products.

For larger displays, consider embedding a webserver in your software and building a tablet into your project...